# jQuery change name on mute button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, mute

i need help with the mute button, i can get all the sound to be muted and Unmuted, but i want the button to change so when you click on mute button, it will change to Unmute on the button

```
function mutebutton() {

var lyden_er_muted = $("#kor").get(0).muted;
if (lyden_er_muted == true) {
    $("#kor").get(0).muted = false;
    $("#snorken").get(0).muted = false;
    $("#tramper").get(0).muted = false;
    $(".mute").text("mute music");
}
else{
    //1: mute lyden
    $("#kor").get(0).muted = true;
    $("#snorken").get(0).muted = true;
    $("#tramper").get(0).muted = true;
    $(".mute").text("Unmute music");
}
}
```

Comment: can u share a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/25935a7t/

Comment: your jsfiddle is incomplete and has a lot of errors. assuming you are setting the click event of your mute button in the document.ready event, if you call $(this).text('Unmute music') in the mutebutton() function, it will work.